# What is the difference with ED and IF-ED lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

I am confused with the difference between 
**Nikon AF-S DX 55-200mm F/4-5.6G Telephoto Lens**
and 
**Nikon 55-200mm f/4-5.6G AF-S VR DX IF-ED Telephoto Zoom Lens**

Can some one clarify me on this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean/508#508

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable. The lenses are very similar indeed, as noted in [comparison / review by Thom Hogan](http://www.bythom.com/55200lens.htm). On Nikkor lenses, ["IF" is an acronym](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/4390/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean) for [internal focusing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22183/4390/what-is-the-benefit-of-an-internal-focus-lens) - so that [using polarizing filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/655/4390/in-which-situations-should-i-use-my-circular-polarizing-filter) should be easier with the IF-ED lens. But the most significant (and costly) difference is actually considered to be VR, standing for Vibration Reduction, which compensates for your hands shaking, helping to keep [longer exposures](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/4390/how-can-i-determine-the-minimum-shutter-speed-to-avoid-blur-from-camera-shake) free from blur caused by that.

Comment: See also for how to decipher all of those cryptic letter and number codes in lens names:    http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean/508#508