# Canon 700d - lens does not move when focusing?

Tags: canon

I have a canon 700d. I have seen other 700d's, and when they focus the lens automatically moves in and out. My one doesn't. Why would that be?

Comment: What lens ae you using? Is it the same lens as on the other cameras that you have seen? What autofocus mode are you in? Does it still autofocus? To answer your question properly we need the answers to at least a few of these questions, preferably all.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on which lens is mounted on the camera. If you have an **EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM** stepping motor lens the front element neither rotates nor moves in and out as it is focusing because it has *[internal focusing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22183/15871)*. Many other lenses, such as the **EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II**, do not feature internal focusing and so the front element rotates and moves in and out as focus is changed.