# Are there any good resources that provides information about the focus breathing of various lenses?

Tags: lens, focus-breathing

Sites like DxOMark provides a lot of information about lenses but they generally don't provide any really usable information about the focus breathing protperties of the lenses. In fact I don't know a single website or other source that systematically tests and presents the focus breathing properties of lenses at different focus distances.

Are there any good resources that provides this information?

Comment: I have not seen any up to the moment. Many review sites include this information into reviews but I have not seen a database for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no resources that specifically note which lenses exhibit "focus breathing". However, many lens databases do note whether lenses use internal focusing mechanisms, which potentially reduces focus breathing.

Unit-focusing and back-focusing lenses would be expected to exhibit focus breathing because the size of the image circle changes with focus. I'm not sure with front-focusing lenses, but I'd expect them to be similar to internal-focusing lenses.

See [What is the benefit of an internal focus lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22183/75526)

Answer (score 0):

If you're really, really curious, you'd have to read into some professional reviews. There isn't a true method for measuring breathing, unlike MTF curves or distortion figures, since it's difficult to quantify, and everyone has a different metric for measuring it. [Ken Rockwell](https://www.kenrockwell.com/) does a pretty good job with qualitatively describing it, but he isn't perfect, and some don't have information.